# Can`t compare ArrayList values in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, compare

Im doing a Java course and in one exercise I have to create three ArrayLists, ask the user to fill the first two with Integers, and then compare both ArrayLists.

The values that don´t repeat are added to the third ArrayList. I already declared the ArrayLists, used Scanner to allow the user to fill the ArrayLists, and that part works.

The problem comes when I try to compare both ArrayLists. I get all sort of alerts in this line (**"the if statement is redundant", "Integer values compared using == or !=","Flip operands of the binary operator", "Invert if"**).

I suspect that what I wrote after the if statement is not very clean, and that I could get some comments about that (Im not an expert in Java), but I do not understand the alerts that the IDE displays. The code compiles and runs just fine until it hits the nested loops. Please help! Thanks.

```
       //Checking for values that dont repeat
        for(int i=0;i<listVector1.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<listVector2.size();i++){
                if(listVector1.get(i)==listVector2.get(j)){//Im getting an alert here
                 repeats=true; //this boolean was previously declared
                 } else {
                  repeats=false;
                }
            if(repeats==false){
                int newValue=listVector1.get(i);
                listVector3.add(newValue);
            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: How do you initialize the ArrayList? Of which type is it?

Comment: In the second for-loop, you are using i++ instead of j++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a mistake in the second for loop. I expect you want increment j.
Second is comparing you must explicit cast your values from the array or use function equals.
Third your if statement must be out of your second loop. Because I expect you want to add number in third array only one time as it you find.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listVector1.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < listVector2.size(); j++) {
        if (listVector1.get(i).equals(listVector2.get(j))) {
            repeats = true;
            break;
        } else {
            repeats = false;
        }
     }
     if(!repeats){
         int newValue=listVector1.get(i);
         listVector3.add(newValue);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I feel like such a dumbass for the first error you pointed out. For the use of "==" instead of the equals method, that was actually a mistake of my professor. I was doubtful about using "break", because it is nested in a if block of code and could cause unexpected behaviour, but Ill try what you are suggesting. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the real problem here.

> Integer values compared using == or !=

The `==` operator compares the two object's reference. But what you actually want to do is compare the values stored in the reference.
So, you need to use the `equals` operator.

Or you could explicitly cast one of the values to `int` and use `==` on the values like

```
if(listVector1.get(i) == ((int)listVector2.get(j))){
     repeats=true; 
} else {
     repeats=false;
}
```

For more reading, you'd google `difference between == and equals operator`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to post this. I was not aware of the equals method for ArrayLists, in fact the professor of the course was the one that suggested "==" to be used this way. Ill try what you are suggesting. Thanks again.